# How to print the array element of a form in another form in vb6.0

Tags: arrays, vb6

I want to store the records for different newspapers with descriptions (like name,price,date of publishing) and want to show them in another form whenever it is loaded. What is the simplest method to do this process without using database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDT (User Defined Type) structure:

```
in MODULE BAS
Public Type TYPE_Newspapers       ' Create your type structure
' Define items
   Name As String * 100
   Price As Currency
   PublishDate As Date
End Type

in Form:    
Public MyNewspapers(1 to 100) As TYPE_Newspapers
With MyNewspapers(1)
    .Name = "Wall Street Journal"
    .Price = 1
    .PublishDate = #01/01/2017#
End With
```

and so on...

Comment: if i want to provide the values at runtime then,also i want to later show the values in another form